# What the reason to use RowSetProvider to obtain RowSetFactory?

Tags: java, jdbc, rowset

I notice that I get same result if I use

```
    RowSetFactory rowSetFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
```

and

```
    rowSetFactory = new RowSetFactoryImpl();
```

`newFactory` method implementation:

```
public static RowSetFactory newFactory()
            throws SQLException {
        // Use the system property first
        RowSetFactory factory = null;
        String factoryClassName = null;
        try {
            trace("Checking for Rowset System Property...");
            factoryClassName = getSystemProperty(ROWSET_FACTORY_NAME);
            if (factoryClassName != null) {
                trace("Found system property, value=" + factoryClassName);
                factory = (RowSetFactory) getFactoryClass(factoryClassName, null, true).newInstance();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new SQLException(
                    "RowSetFactory: " + factoryClassName + " not found", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException(
                    "RowSetFactory: " + factoryClassName + " could not be instantiated: " + e,
                    e);
        }
```

Here we see that this method returns `RowSetFactory` which set in system.property.

What the reason to change this system property?

Who does set this property by default?

Comment: You only get the same result if the system property hasn't been set explicitly... BTW: Your question is answered in the API doc: there can be alternative implementations, I fail to see why you need to ask this question.

Comment: Ok. I want to know situations when I should to use alternative implementation. and what can be different in alternative implementation?

Comment: The primary reason would be if that other implementation provides better support or fixes bugs; think of database implementation specific tricks to simply loading, refreshing or storing the data in the rowset. However, I don't actually know if there are any alternative implementations available.

Answer (score 0):

The `com.sun.rowset.RowSetFactoryImpl` class (see [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.sql.rowset/share/classes/com/sun/rowset/RowSetFactoryImpl.java)) is but one of possibly several concrete implementations of the [`RowSetFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetFactory.html) interface.

`RowSetProvider` & `RowSetFactory` make it easy to find default implementations as well as give you the flexibility to customize for particular implementations.

You can see this in the Javadoc of `RowSetProvider`.

- Default:
  `RowSetProvider.newFactory()`
- Custom:
  `RowSetProvider.newFactory("com.sun.rowset.RowSetFactoryImpl", null)`