# Returning resultSet in java JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

How can i return ResultSet from a method while closing the connection and preparedStatement? when i am closing connection and prepared statement, it is giving an exception that 'the connection is closed'. can i skip the closing part in this case?

Comment: Yes, don't close the connection in this case. The ResultSet does not contain all the data right away but might retrieve parts of it when you call `next()`. That requires the connection to still be open.

Comment: If I recall, once the ResultSet has been used for a query, the reference to that ResultSet is cleared. You would need to query again to get reference to another ResultSet. Once you have run the query, place the ResultSet into a List Interface of Object (`List<Object>`).

Comment: You should not return a ResultSet, ever.  You should load the response into an object or collection and close the ResultSet in method scope.  A ResultSet is a cursor on the database server.  You lose responsibility to close it if you return it to the caller.  Your app risks exhausting cursors with this arrangement.

Comment: @duffymo On the contrary, some of the sub-interfaces of `RowSet` (itself a sub-interface of `ResultSet`) are indeed designed to return a `ResultSet`. Implementations of those `RowSet` interfaces resolve the cursor issue in various ways.

Comment: I do not recommend it.   Please feel feee to do as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

## `RowSet`

If you really want to return a `ResultSet` after closing a connection, use its sub-interface, [`RowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/RowSet.html).

More specifically, you will want one of the disconnected `RowSet` types. These include:

- [`CachedRowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html)
- [`WebRowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/WebRowSet.html)
- [`JoinRowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/JdbcRowSet.html)
- [`FilteredRowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/FilteredRowSet.html)

… as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html#kinds_of_rowset_objects).

For more info, do [a Web search](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/RowSet.html). And see *The Java Tutorials* by Oracle Corp free-of-cost, [*Using RowSet Objects*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html). And search Stack Overflow to learn more.

To get a `RowSet` object, you will need an implementation of the interfaces. In modern Java, the [`RowSetProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetProvider.html) and [`RowSetFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetFactory.html) classes are used to automatically locate the presence of an implementation. Discussed on [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25592162/642706).

A JDK based on the OpenJDK codebase will likely come bundled with the open-source [`com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.sql.rowset/share/classes/com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl.java) implementation of `CachedRowSet` used in example code below.

Caveat: The *RowSet* feature in Java seems to have gone largely ignored by much of the Java community, for reasons I cannot fathom. I suspect it came too late, after many folks moved onto other paradigms, and [ORMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping), and such. But a `RowSet` does provide precisely what you asked for: A `ResulSet` that works after closing the `Connection`.

### Example code

Here is a complete example app of a `CachedRowSet` containing data *after* disconnecting from database.

This code uses the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)). The created database is in-memory, no file storage, so it is ephemeral.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider;
import java.sql.*;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Example of using a disconnected RowSet, specifically a CachedRowSet,
 * to keep a ResultSet even after disconnecting from database.
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World! " + Instant.now() );
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        DataSource dataSource = this.getDataSource();
        this.createDatabase( dataSource );
        this.populateTable( dataSource );
        this.dumpTable( dataSource );
        CachedRowSet rowSet = this.fetchRowSet( dataSource );
        this.reportRowSet( rowSet );
    }

    private DataSource getDataSource ( )
    {
        JdbcDataSource ds = new JdbcDataSource(); // The `javax.sql.DataSource` interface implemented by `org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource`.
        ds.setURL( "jdbc:h2:mem:" + "RowSetExDb" + ";DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" );  // Set delay to -1 to keep in-memory database even after last connection closed.
        ds.setUser( "scott" );
        ds.setPassword( "tiger" );
        ds.setDescription( "Dummy database for demo showing how to use a RowSet after closing connection." );
        return ds; // Generalizing from the concrete class to the interface.
    }

    private void createDatabase ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
        )
        {
            try ( Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ; )
            {
                String sql =
                        """
                        CREATE TABLE person_ ( 
                            pkey_ UUID DEFAULT random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY , 
                            name_ VARCHAR NOT NULL 
                        ) ;
                        """;
                stmt.execute( sql );
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    private void populateTable ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
        )
        {
            String sql =
                    """
                    INSERT INTO person_ ( name_ ) 
                    VALUES ( ? ) 
                    ;
                    """;

            List < String > names = List.of( "Alice" , "Bob" , "Carol" , "Davis" ); // Insert a row for each of these names.
            System.out.println( "Inserting list of names: " + names );
            try (
                    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
            )
            {
                for ( String name : names )
                {
                    ps.setString( 1 , name );
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    private void dumpTable ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
        )
        {
            // Retrieve rows from a `ResultSet`.
            String sql =
                    """
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM person_ 
                    ;
                    """;
            try (
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
            )
            {
                record Person( UUID id , String name ) { }
                while ( rs.next() )
                {
                    UUID pkey = rs.getObject( "pkey_" , UUID.class );
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    System.out.println( new Person( pkey , name ) );
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    private CachedRowSet fetchRowSet ( final DataSource dataSource )
    {
        try (
                Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
        )
        {
            // Retrieve rows from a `ResultSet`.
            String sql =
                    """
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM person_ 
                    ;
                    """;
            try (
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ;
            )
            {
                CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();
                crs.populate( rs );
                return crs;
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }

    private void reportRowSet ( final CachedRowSet cachedRowSet )
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println( "*****|  CachedRowSet without Connection  |**************" );
            while ( cachedRowSet.next() )
            {
                String pkey = cachedRowSet.getString( "pkey_" );  // Using `String` rather than `UUID` as the default implementation of CachedRowSet does not support accessing as UUID object.
                String name = cachedRowSet.getString( "name_" );

                String message = "pkey = " + pkey + " | name = " + name;
                System.out.println( message );
            }
            System.out.println( "**************************************************" );
        }
        catch ( SQLException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Hello World! 2022-08-07T23:26:43.721898Z
Inserting list of names: [Alice, Bob, Carol, Davis]
Person[id=8c5329fd-5abb-4a65-ad41-5e32914b166b, name=Alice]
Person[id=6ed97068-ed14-4be4-a2a0-0bf4ad113862, name=Bob]
Person[id=91b335b5-aa6f-4689-b2f4-eff2fea51d76, name=Carol]
Person[id=d600cffe-1c65-4e33-bfb1-59ac1b4de7af, name=Davis]
*****|  CachedRowSet without Connection  |**************
pkey = 8c5329fd-5abb-4a65-ad41-5e32914b166b | name = Alice
pkey = 6ed97068-ed14-4be4-a2a0-0bf4ad113862 | name = Bob
pkey = 91b335b5-aa6f-4689-b2f4-eff2fea51d76 | name = Carol
pkey = d600cffe-1c65-4e33-bfb1-59ac1b4de7af | name = Davis
**************************************************
```

Note that a `RowSet` object is also a `ResultSet` object. You can use a `RowSet` wherever you would have used a `ResultSet`, subject to the limits of its interface and class implementation.

## `record`

Another approach is to define a [Data-Transfer Object (DTO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

The new [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) feature in Java 16+ can be ideal for this purpose of communicating data transparently and immutably. With a record, you merely declare the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, accessors, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

You write code to loop through your `ResultSet` rows, copying the data into record objects, and storing in a `List` or `Set`.

See example code above for a record being declared locally, and instantiated with data retrieved from database. Excerpt:

```java
                record Person( UUID id , String name ) { }
                while ( rs.next() )
                {
                    UUID pkey = rs.getObject( "pkey_" , UUID.class );
                    String name = rs.getString( "name_" );
                    System.out.println( new Person( pkey , name ) );
                }
```

You could make a new [`List< Person >`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html), and [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#add(E)) each new `Person` object.

Comment: The reference implementation of rowset included in Java has a number of bugs and inconsistencies with normal JDBC. Personally, I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query and obtain a ResultSet, the data has not yet transferred from the database into your JVM. Consider having a huge database, much larger than your RAM (that is usually the reason to run a database at all) and therefore you need to process the result record by record.

The pattern is to

```
while (rs.next()) {
    // do something about the record loaded into the ResultSet now
}
rs.close();
```

If you close the database connection before you looped through the resultset you eliminate the chance of loading further records. The exception just indicates this situation.

On the other hand, not closing the resultset would mean you wait until it gets garbage collected. Until then it stays in memory, and the database needs to stay ready to deliver the data in case next() were called. That also means all records that may be locked stay locked until the garbage collector kicks in - which may result in performance penalties or even deadlocks.

The question would be why you need to close the connection before processing the data.

Comment: Because i returned the ResultSet to another method and there i can't close the connection and a unclosed connection is bad right?

Comment: Yes, you cannot slimply return the result set to another method. You need a different way.