# java.sql.SQLException: Provider com.sun.rowset.RowSetFactoryImpl not found

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, rowset, cachedrowset

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77003081/retrieve-data-from-resultset-before-closing-the-connections?noredirect=1#comment135747373_77003081) on how to retrieve data from ResultSet before closing the connections.

JDK Version: jdk1.8.0_201

`CachedRowSet` class is suggested in an answer by someone in the above mentioned question. I've tried going with that approach but got an exception when try to run the program.

> java.sql.SQLException: Provider com.sun.rowset.RowSetFactoryImpl not found

As per my analysis, packages of `com.sun` are internal and are subjected to change. They should never be used except by JDK developers.

Suggest me something to resolve this.

Here is my code

```
/*--- Imports of classes---*/
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider;
/*--- End of Imports ---*/

public ResultSet getUSStates() throws SQLException {
    _log.info("Calling stored proc for ocrt give data");

    try(Connection inGlobalConnections = getConnection();
        CallableStatement callableStatement = inGlobalConnections.prepareCall("{call mst.USP_GetUSStates()}");
        ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.getResultSet();) {

        callableStatement.execute();

        CachedRowSet cachedRowSet = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();
        cachedRowSet.populate(resultSet);

        return cachedRowSet;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _log.error(e, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Packages with `com.sun` are not necessarily internal (there are libraries out there that use the same prefix), it is packages with `sun.*` which are internal. In any case, it would be helpful to know your Java version, the Java vendor, and whether or not you have a `module-info.java`, and if so, what its contents are.

Comment: That said, the `com.sun.rowset.*` packages included in Java are considered "not-public" and should be accessed only through the `javax.sql.rowset.*` API.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Apologies for the confusion, I've edited my question by adding JDK version. I don't know whether I'm right or not but `module-info.java` is not present in `jdk1.8.0_201 or earlier`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why are you using such an old Java version? The latest Java 8 is Java 8 update 381/382. Also, which vendor, is this Oracle, AdoptOpenJDK/Eclipse Adoptium, Azul, some other JVM vendor?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If I try with latest java 8 version, will this issue resolve?

Comment: I don't know, try it, I'd say.

Comment: All I can say is that with Eclipse Adoptium Java 8 update 382, the line `RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet()` executes without an error and produces a rowset of type `com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl`.

Comment: Also, while `com.sun` classes are internal, it *is* being used internally here. Your code is not referring to any `com.sun` classes, only `javax.sql` classes. So that need not concern you.

Comment: I have never used these RowSet classes, why not just save your resultset into a list of rows? You'll have to do it eventually anyway